# how to refresh the list in jquery javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i m having one page with one textbox named search and one search button. When i'm searching anything for the first time it's showing me the right data but when i'm searching some other things for the next time then the elements which was listed before are also appended below of that new list. Suppose i'm searching state name by k it will give me right list of karnataka, kerala. But if  i start to search again by g, it will show me in output as goa,gujrat,karnataka kerala. i tried using refresh option but it still not working. This is my js code

```
$.each(response.state, function (i, state) {
$('#statelist').append(

               '<li>' +
                   '<a href="#">' 
                   +
                      +'<b>'+ '<font color="green">'+'<h3>'+ state.Name +'</h3>'+'</font>' +'</b>'+

                   '</a>' +
               '</li>'
           );
       });
       $('li img').width(100); 


   $('.ui-li-icon li').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    text = $(this).text();
   // alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
$("#statelist").listview("refresh");
```

and this is html

Comment: look into the `.empty` jquery function http://api.jquery.com/empty/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using .append() function. It appends whatever you append to the end of the list.
Check this link:
http://api.jquery.com/append/

Try using innerHTML property of the DOM model.

Comment: I do not know much JQuery but I would do something like:
    document.getElementById("statelist").innerHTML = "<li><a href="#">Whatever goes in here</a></li>";

Answer (score 0):

You could add

```
If(!('#statelist').html() == ""){
    $(this).remove();
    //execute rest of code that appends state list
}
```

Then do an else statement and execute your append code without removing()

UPDATE: a better option is to do this-

```
$.each(response.state, function (i, state) {
$('#statelist').html(

           '<li>' +
               '<a href="#">' 
               +
                  +'<b>'+ '<font color="green">'+'<h3>'+ state.Name +'</h3>'+'</font>' +'</b>'+

               '</a>' +
           '</li>'
       );
   });
   $('li img').width(100); 


$('.ui-li-icon li').click(function() {
 var index = $(this).index();
 text = $(this).text();
// alert('Index is: ' + index + ' and text is ' + text);
});
```

Comment: Thank you and sorry that last one did not work. I updated my answer with something a bit more concrete